# How to configure nginx + Unicorn to avoid timeout errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, timeout, unicorn

I have a Rails (v3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0) application running on nginx + Unicorn (Ubuntu 12.04). All is working well, except when an admin user is uploading users (thousands) via a CVS file. The problem is that I have set timeout to 30 seconds and the import process takes much more time. So, after 30 seconds I get an nginx 502 Bad Gateway page (Unicorn worker is killed).

The obvious solution is to increase timeout, but I don't want this because it'll cause another problems (I guess), because it's not a typical behavior.

Is there a way to handle this kind of problems?

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: Maybe a solutions is to modify the code. If so, I want to avoid the user to perform another request.

Some ideas (don't know if possible):

- Setup a worker dedicated to this request.
- Send a "work in progress" signal to Unicorn to avoid to be killed.

**nginx-app.conf**

```
upstream xxx {
  server unix:/tmp/xxx.socket fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
  listen   80; 

  ...

  location / {

    proxy_pass  http://xxx;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    ...

    proxy_connect_timeout      360;
    proxy_send_timeout         360;
    proxy_read_timeout         360;
  }
}
```

**unicorn.rb**

```
worker_processes 2

listen "/tmp/xxx.socket"

timeout 30

pid "/tmp/unicorn.xxx.pid"
```

Comment: too short PS, please make it longer.

Comment: Just a note. Your `proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_send_timeout`, `proxy_read_timeout` values are abnormal big. Please, read the documentation, you're probably do not understand their meaning. And `fail_timeout=0` is absolutely meaningless.

Comment: Thank you @VBart. I'll review documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a good reason to create a queue.
And you will:

- upload csv file (that should be within 30sec)
- your background job that will import user data (that can go for hours…)
- while this job is in progress you can serve some kind of WIP page with job status/percents/etc.

Check https://github.com/resque/resque for example. There is a lot of other queues.

Comment: This way you can do a lot of things… like sending 1000s of emails, converting videos/images… Lots of things.

Comment: Is Resque essentially the same thing as Ruby Thread? Or am I way off? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html

Comment: Nope. This is Message Queue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). Resque itself uses threads, sure. Thread is for parallel processing. Queue for asynchronous processing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to handle this kind of problems?

Do the job in background. You should have a separate process that gets jobs from queue one by one and processes them. And since it doesn't work with user requests, it can do its job as long as needed. You don't need unicorn for this, just a separate daemon.