# How to split my inserts into smaller pieces?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, import

This is my importing script. I have about 400 000 records. And my connection closing during inserting records. How to split that to smaller pieces?

```
  def extract_to_database(collection)
    tmp       = []
    type      = K
    inserts = []

    collection.each_with_index do |line, i|
      _type    = line.strip
      _changed = TYPES.include? _type

      if _changed && i > 0
        case type
        when K then @k << tmp
        when F then @f << tmp
        when FB then @f << tmp
        when I, D
          pharmaceutic = Pharmaceutic.find_by pzn: tmp[PZN]
          if pharmaceutic
            inserts.push "(#{pharmaceutic.id}, '#{tmp[UNIT]}', '#{tmp[DOSE]}')"
          end
        end

        tmp  = []
        type = _type
      end

      tmp << clean(line)
    end
    sql = "INSERT INTO pharmaceutic_dosages (`pharmaceutic_id`, `unit`, `dose`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
    CONN.execute sql
  end
```

Comment: What's the actual issue you are facing ?

Comment: This could be an X,Y question, where you're chasing a solution down path X, when really you're trying to solve Y which could have an entirely different, and better and/or more efficient solution, if you'd tell us more about the data, and your database. Turning off automatic indexing can speed up updates/inserts, as can turning off commits and periodically committing after *n* records. You say your connection is closing, but don't tell us if there are errors generated, which there should be, but don't give us the actual text.

Comment: Also, don't open your database connection until you're ready to use it. You don't show when/where you connect, but it's considered bad form to open it, leave it hanging for some indeterminate time, then eventually use it. Open connections use resources on servers, so when you're loading data, open the connection, do what you need to do immediately, then disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of needed information missing from your question, in particular, the DBM you're using, what your timeout values are set to, where in your code you open your database connection, how long it actually takes for your code to process the 400,000 records, etc. All of those things affect the success or failure of your job.

This code caught my eye:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pharmaceutic_dosages (`pharmaceutic_id`, `unit`, `dose`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
CONN.execute sql
```

Where are you opening your connection to the database? Why do you open it then not immediately use it? Databases are configured to close unused connections after a period of time, because connections take up memory and CPU time. Once you connect, send your updates/deletes/inserts, whatever, then close it. You only want a long lasting connection if you'd be constantly connecting/closing, which can be a big CPU drain for the DBM/server too.

Instead of opening then holding the connection while you compute, wait to open it until your data is ready, then open it and immediately send. I don't know what driver or DBM you're using so consider this pseudo-code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pharmaceutic_dosages (`pharmaceutic_id`, `unit`, `dose`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"    
CONN = connect_to_database(...)
CONN.execute sql
CONN.close
```

Do it that way and I doubt you'll see timeout errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is closing on inserting the records, why not just have the script write the SQL statements to a file, then run those inserts against the database?

So:

1. Generate your SQL statements as in the script above.
2. Write them to a file (either locally or on S3).
3. Copy the contents of that file and run in the database console.

Seems like this would prevent OOM errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue some time ago. The best solution I found was using a background job with resque. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138047/how-to-configure-nginx-unicorn-to-avoid-timeout-errors#18161912) answer.

I also used [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) to show the WIP to the user.